# Access nodejs static method using a string variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, variables

I have imported a few classes in Adonis

```
const User = use('App/Models/User')
const Orders = use('App/Models/Orders')
```

I want to be able to access one of the above classes dynamically. By that I mean a variable will hold the class I want to access. The variable will be populated by via an API call from the user.

```
let className = 'Orders'
```

How to I use the `className` variable to access the Orders class.

I have tried

```
[className].query().where('orderNumber','123').fetch()
```

However that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `name -> class` map:

```
const classes = {
  __proto__: null, // to avoid people being able to pass something like `toString`
  Users,
  Orders,
};
// or if you don't want to use __proto__
const classes = Object.assign(
  Object.create(null),
  {Users, Orders}
);
```

and access the right class with `classes[className]`. Of course verify whether the class exists or not.

---

> I have tried
>
> ```
> [className].query().where('orderNumber','123').fetch()
> ```
>
> However that does not seem to work.

In this context, `[...]` denotes an array literal, so `[className]` just creates an array containing `className` (which is a string in your example) as only element.

Comment: Nice little workaround, and simple object to represent each possible class.

Comment: Yeah, concise properties (or whatever it's called) are really nice for that.

Comment: Very good thank you. I tried and it works. I will accept this answer.

Comment: @FelixKling This`__proto__: null` line was pure gold.

Comment: I'm a little worried though. Big huge red boxes for `__proto__` at the top: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: I'd most likely use: `const classes = Object.create(null, {
  Users,
  Orders,
});`

Comment: @FrankerZ: `Object.create` needs property descriptors as second argument. A normal object won't work. `Object.assign(Object.create(null), {Users, Orders}))` would work. Regarding `__proto__`: I always thought *accessing* `__proto__` is deprecated, but using it an object literal is OK. [It's part of the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-__proto__-property-names-in-object-initializers). However, it's in the browser specific addendum and so maybe it should still be avoided .... (and may not actually work in Node).

Answer (score 0):

Avoid converting the variable to a string at all. Just use:

```
let className = Orders;
className.query().where('orderNumber','123').fetch()
```

If the class is being instantiated by an API call, use a simple switch statement:

```
let class;
switch (apiCall.name) {
    case 'orders':
        class = Orders;
        break;
    case 'users':
        class = Users;
        break;
    default:
        throw 'Invalid API Call';
}

class.query().where('orderNumber','123').fetch()
```

Comment: I need to access the class dynamically. The name of the class will be passed in by the user via an API call.

Comment: You should have mentioned the API call in your original question.

Comment: I have updated the question to explain what I mean by dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to `eval(className).query().where('orderNumber','123').fetch()`, but if you want to check the values existence as an actual class, you probably should implement a switch or if-else-if to check and assign className and call only if it is actually present.

Comment: When mentioning `eval()`, you should also mention how evil it is. It creates many security holes, and usually does more harm than good. I cannot in good conscience recommend this solution.

Comment: Never `eval` user input.

Comment: @FrankerZ I wanted to add a disclaimer, but then I didn't. :D

Comment: @FelixKling As long as we have santized the input before calling eval() it is no issue.

Comment: How do you sanitize it? If you're not 100% sure you're sanitizing for anything the user could throw, than evaling input afterwards could be very dangerous. Avoiding eval all together eliminates many security issues.

Comment: Sure, but if you check whether `className` is an existing class name, you may as well load the actual class, just like FrankerZ did, and so there is no need for `eval` `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.